# Using Facebook FB.ui shared dialog to also see generator URL page like count

Tags: javascript, facebook, sdk, share

Using the normal facebook sharer you can generator a snippet of code that will also display the "page" like count.

example

```
     https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/like-button
```

Although for this case I am using the FB.ui that looks something like this

```
          javascript:
  (function(d, s, id) {
      var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
      if (d.getElementById(id))
          return;
      js = d.createElement(s);
      js.id = id;
      js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
      fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
  }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));

  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
      FB.init({
          appId: 'comingsoon',
          status: true,
          xfbml: true,
          cookie: true
      });
  };

  $(document).ready(function() {
      $('.fb-share').click(function() {
          FB.ui({
              method: 'feed',
              name: 'test',
              link: "http://localhost:3000/posts/"+postID+"",
              picture: postPHOTO,
              description: postDESC
          });
      });
  });
```

This works great and generates the dialog and posts the correct link, image, etc.

Although the question is how with this can I also generator(with some callback) the page like count so I can display it next to the custom facebook share button?  My guess is that some javascript will have to see the exact dynamic/URL I build up "http://localhost:3000/posts/"+postID+"" and then perform some action call to fb to get a integer?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Why have the like count next to the share button when they have nothing to do with each other?